# $f$ is a differentiable map and compute $Df(A)(H)$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus

Let $f : GL(n, \Bbb R) \to GL(n, \Bbb R)$ be defined by $f(A) = A^{-1}$ where derivative of the matrix $A$ exists. Then $f$ is a differentiable map and compute $Df(A)(H)$.

$A A^{-1} = I \implies \frac{dA}{dt} A^{-1} + A\ \frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}  = 0 \implies \frac{dA^{-1}}{dt} = - A^{-1} \frac{dA}{dt} A^{-1}$.

I can find the derivative of $A^{-1}$ but what will be the derivative of $A^{-1}$ in the direction of H i.e. $Df(A)(H)$?

Help Needed!

Answer (score 1):

Given $A, H\in GL(n,\Bbb R)$, let $C = A^{-1}H$ and consider $E(t) := t^2 C^2(I + tC)^{-1}$. Then $E(t) = o(t)$ as $t\to 0$ and $(I + tC)^{-1} = I - tC + E(t)$. So

$$(A + tH)^{-1} = (I + tC)^{-1}A^{-1} = A^{-1} - tCA^{-1} + E(t)A^{-1} = A^{-1} - tCA^{-1} + o(t),$$

which implies

$$df(A)(H) = -CA^{-1} = -A^{-1}HA^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is an inaccuracy in your computation, your conclusion about the derivative of $A^{-1}$ is correct. Directional derivative in the direction $H$ just means that$$\frac{dA}{dt}=H.$$Substituting in your formula we get$$df(A)(H)=\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}=-A^{-1}HA^{-1}.$$

**Edit:** When differentiating $AA^{-1}=I$, the right equation is$$\frac{dA}{dt}A^{-1}+A\frac{dA^{-1}}{dt}=0.$$Since marix multiplication is non-commutative, this equation is not equivalent to the one written in the post.

Comment: can you please state the computation of derivative of $A^{-1}$

Comment: @user8795 Please see the edit in my answer.